# How to prevent a block section item in a VF page to referesh

Tags: visualforce

So I have an entire page for data entry that's enclosed in an outputPanel called InputSec, which is called a couple of times to   rerender the entire page. There's one block section item called "Birthln" that I don't want to refresh everytime a rerender is executed for InputSec. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple technique here would be to break the form into multiple logical sections, where each logical section is enclosed in a separate `<apex:outputPanel>`. This will offer the flexibility to choose which sections to reRender on specific server method calls.

Considering you have divided the page into multiple sections each enclosed in a separate `<apex:outputPanel>` then the pseudo Visualforce code for the same would be as below.

```
<apex:page controller="YourControllerClass">

    <apex:form>

        <apex:outputPanel id="pnl1"> Logical Section 1 </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="pnl2"> Logical Section 2 </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="pnl2"> Logical Section 3 </apex:outputPanel>


        <apex:commandButton id="btnOne" action="{!doSomething}" reRender="pnl1, pnl2, pnl3"/>
        <apex:commandButton id="btnTwo" action="{!doSomethingAgain}" reRender="pnl1, pnl3"/>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jigar.  I was able break some of my block sections and selectively use them in method calls and fixed my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help.